ScalarDL How you can filter assets by their id
Suppose asset id has the format “{company_name}-{token_name}” How to filter all assets by “company_name” or by occurrence of “token_name”.
For example: I have asset id:
“my_company-mather1”.
“my_company-mather2”
“my_company-bro2” and ...
I want to get all assets “my_company-mather”
I tried com.scalar.dl.ledger.database.AssetFilter but it expects a specific asset id and supposedly it is not suitable for me to filter all assets.
